# Distance of one dimensional quantum error correcting code

Tags: error-correction, resource-request, fault-tolerance, graph-states, cluster-states

Consider one dimensional quantum codes $[[ n,k=0]] $.
One way to describe them is using stabilizer framework with $n$ independent Pauli matrices.
Usually, one considers them in the graph state model as well.
If you use the distance definition by treating them as stabilizer codes, then as $N(S)=S$, it would detect all errors.
Is there a notion of distance of such graph states?
I have seen distance being defined after restriction that they are non-degenerate with a mention that graph states are traditionally treated as non-degenerate. Are there any applications where this distance (or some other notion of distance of graph states) plays an important role?

Comment: A one-dimensional stabiliser code is just a stabiliser state; the distance of a state is ill-defined. But yeah, if you encode a state, and you know what state, you'll always be able to correct for an error.

Comment: BTW - a one dimensional quantum error correcting code is not necessarily a cluster state (in the usual sense of the word). Cluster states are a particular type of graph states, which are themselves a subset of the set of stabiliser states. Every graph state is local-clifford equivalent to a graph state, though.

Comment: see previous post : https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/13354/how-to-calculate-distance-of-k-0-stabilizer-code  I think d=infinity makes sense

Answer (score 1):

The distance of an $[[n, 0]]$ code is defined to be the smallest non-zero weight of any stabilizer.